# Error passing value to dictionary from one cshtml form to other

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had this MVC form that I want to pass Gridview value to another MVC form.  I want the user to click on the WorkUnitID then it will retrieve all the value from the database and pass those values (Worker First Name, Last Name, Supervisor Name, Case Number) to other form where it can be added to different database.  See code below.  The form error out when passing value to add.cshtml with following message :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[CalFresh.Models.calfreshByWorkUnitID]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CalFresh.Models.calfreshByWorkUnitID'. )

I am trying to find out what did I do wrong here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CalFresh.Models
{
    public class calfreshByWorkUnitID
    {
        public string tempWorkUnitID { get; set; }

        public string tempWorkerFirstName { get; set; }

        public string tempWorkerLastName { get; set; }

        public string tempWorkerSupervisor { get; set; }

        public string tempCalWINCaseNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CalFreshListController.cs

```
        public ActionResult Add(int?id)
        {
            if (id ==null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var    calFrestList = (from m in     db.vw_clerk_work_unit_activities
                                                   where m.work_unit_id == id
                                                   select new calfreshByWorkUnitID
                                                   {
                                                       tempWorkUnitID = m.work_unit_id.ToString(),
                                                       tempWorkerFirstName = m.assignedEmpFirst,
                                                       tempWorkerLastName = m.assignedEmpLast,
                                                       tempCalWINCaseNumber = m.calwin_case_number,
                                                       tempWorkerSupervisor = m.assignedEmpManager
                                                   });


        if (calFrestList == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(calFrestList);        

        }
    }
```

add.cshtml

```
@model CalFresh.Models.calfreshByWorkUnitID

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.tempWorkUnitID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.tempWorkerFirstName, htmlAttributes:    new { @class="control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.tempWorkerFirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class="form-control"}})
    </div>
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is expecting a single instance of type `calfreshByWorkUnitID`.  But the `calFrestList` variable is not that.  It is of type `DbQuery<calfreshByWorkUnitID>`.  Which means it is a potential collection of that model.

It looks like you just want one instance to be returned from your query.  If that's the case, you'd just have to add something like `.SingleOrDefault()` on the end of the LINQ statement.  For example:

```
var calFrestList = (from m in db.vw_clerk_work_unit_activities
                    ...
                   ).SingleOrDefault();
```

This would execute the `DbQuery` and materialize the results, expecting a single record (or `null` if no record, which you then check for in the next line already).

Comment: Thank you David!  That's it.